# How do I get the phoneModel name?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get a list of the most expensive phone models from each manufacturer? Now it outputs only the companyId and price, I don't understand how to get the phoneModel name

```
SELECT 
    companyId,
    max(price)
FROM phone
group by companyId;
```

[image]

Comment: Add `phoneModel` in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @Ergest Basha: Then you get the most expensive phone model per company and model. And this would be all phone models in the table of course. They are looking for the most expensive phones per company only.

Comment: @Nico Haase: They have tried the query they are showing, and they don't know how to add the phone model to that select list. MySQL does not feature `KEEP FIRST/LAST` like Oracle, so there is no aggregation function available for this. This means the OP needs a different kind of query.

Comment: I don't see the reason this got closed. Had the OP known that this is called a "top n per group" query they might have found the solution, but obviously they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done with a window function:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    phone.*,
    max(price) over(partition by companyid) as max_price
  from phone
) with_max_price_per_company
where price = max_price;
```

An alternative is

```
select *
from phone p
where price = (select max(price) from phone p2 where p2.companyid = p.companyid);
```

or

```
select *
from phone
where company, price) in
(
  select company, max(price)
  from phone
  group by companyid
);
```

or

```
select * from phone p
where not exists
(
  select null
  from phone p2
  where p2.companyid = p.companyid
  and p2.price > p.price
);
```